# How can the roots of $x^4 - 16 = 0$ be $2$, $-2$, $-2i$ and $2i$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How can the roots of the equation $x^4 - 16 = 0$ be $2$, $-2$, $-2i$ and $2i$? Wouldn't it just be $2$ and $-2$? I don't know where $-2i$ and $2i$ came from. Please explain in the simplest way. Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity or  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RootofUnity.html

Comment: Couldn't you've just goggled "i math", even if you didn't know $i$ was for imaginary? Check the first result please.

Answer (score 5):

This is simply repeated application of the difference of squares formula $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b),$$ together with the fact that $i^2=-1.$ In particular, $$\begin{align}x^4-16 &= (x^2)^2-4^2\\ &= (x^2+4)(x^2-4)\\ &=  (x^2+2^2)(x^2-2^2)\\ &= \bigl(x^2-2^2\cdot(-1)\bigr)(x+2)(x-2)\\ &= (x^2-2^2i^2)(x+2)(x-2)\\ &= \bigl(x^2-(2i)^2\bigr)(x+2)(x-2)\\ &= (x+2i)(x-2i)(x+2)(x-2).\end{align}$$ Hence, our roots are $\pm 2i,$ as well as $\pm 2.$

Answer (score 3):

Simply because: $2^4=16$ , $(-2)^4=16$ , $(-2i)^4=-2^4\times(i)^4=16\times1$  , $2i^4=2^4\times i^4=16$

Comment: Shouldn't there be parentheses around the $-2$? That is, $(-2)^4$ instead of $-2^4$.

Comment: @JMCF125: yes. Of course

Answer (score 2):

$(x^4 - 16) = (x^2 - 4) (x^2 + 4) = (x - 2) (x + 2) (x^2 + 4)$. Then, you have the real roots at $x=2$ and $x=-2$ but you also have the values which cancel $x^2 + 4$; that means that $x^2 = - 4 = 4 i^2$, then the two imaginary roots $x = 2 i$ and $x = - 2 i$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4-16 = 0 \implies  (x^2-4)(x^2+4) = 0 \implies x^2-4=0\text{ or } x^2+4=0$$

$x=\pm 2$ are solutions to $x^2-4=0$, whereas $x=\pm 2i$ are solutions to $x^2+4=0$ if you allow for complex solutions.

Answer (score 2):

$2i$ and $-2i$ are the complex roots of the equation, and $2$ and $-2$ are the real roots of the equation.

$(x^4-16)=(x^2-4)(x^2+4)=0$

or, equivalently $x^2+4=0$ which gives us roots $\pm2i(\text{here i is known as complex square root of unity or } i=\sqrt{-1})$ and $x^2-4=0$ which gives us roots $\pm2.$

Comment: You meant square root, I guess.

Comment: @user37238 Thank you for pointing that, i was doing a question on complex that time, must have slipped :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you know obviously that the fourth root of 1 is nothing other than $1,-1,i,-i$ and fortunately we have $(16)^{\frac 14}=2.(1)^{\frac 14}$ so...!